# Single click to edit a JTable Cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

currently the JTable cell is selected on first click, and on the second one it is edited.

Is it possible to directly edit it on the first click?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the DefaultCellEditor api there is a method named [setClickCountToStart](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html#setClickCountToStart%28int%29)

```
    DefaultCellEditor singleclick = new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextField());
    singleclick.setClickCountToStart(1);

    //set the editor as default on every column
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        table.setDefaultEditor(table.getColumnClass(i), singleclick);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, this dosent seem to work, it works with javax.swing.table.TableColumn col = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
DefaultCellEditor singleclick = new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextField());
singleclick.setClickCountToStart(1);
col.setCellEditor (singleclick); This works for only 1 column, is it possible for the entire table at once?

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<table.getColumnModel().getColumnCount();i++){
                TableColumn col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
                col.setCellEditor (singleclick); 
            }` but thats not the beautiful way

Answer (score 8):

The posted answer regarding extending DefaultCellEditor does work, and I have used it, except that on changing our application's Look&Feel to Nimbus, the thicker default JTextField border encroaches into the table cell making the text within unreadable.

The reason is that the default table cell editor is JTable$GenericEditor not DefaultCellEditor (of which it is a direct subclass) and the former has the following crucial line in `getTableCellEditorComponent()`:

```
((JComponent)getComponent()).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
```

JTable$GenericEditor is package private so can't be subclassed, but JTable provides a `getDefaultEditor()` method, so all I do is:

```
((DefaultCellEditor) myJTable.getDefaultEditor(Object.class)).setClickCountToStart(1);
```

or if you wanted to cater for all possible columnClasses in your table (in case one of your columns was a Number for example):

```
for (int i = 0; i < myJTable.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {
    final DefaultCellEditor defaultEditor = (DefaultCellEditor) myJTable.getDefaultEditor(myJTable.getColumnClass(i));
    defaultEditor.setClickCountToStart(1);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use`setClickCountToStart(1)` on the cell editor.