# How to clear a selected cell in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I can select and set focus to cells in a `JTable` by clicking it, now I want to change the value on the focused cell. In order to change the value of it, I have to double click! Is there any way to clear/change the value of that focused cell (by single-clicking)?

I have tried `jTable1.setValueAt("", row, column);`, this clears the value in the background(It's not updated in the GUI/Same old value appears in the cell).

Table structure:

[image: table structure]

```
jTable1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount()==1){
            final JTable jTable=(JTable)e.getSource();
            final int row = jTable.getSelectedRow();
            final int column = jTable.getSelectedColumn();
            jTable1.editCellAt(row,column);
            jTable1.getEditorComponent().requestFocus();
            final Double valueInCell = (Double)jTable.getValueAt(row, column);
            System.out.println(valueInCell);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you after this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/7387099/932359

Answer (score -2):

If all you desire is to clear or change a JTable cell that holds Strings, why not simply call JTable's `setValueAt(Object o, int row, int column)` method?  To clear, pass in `""`, to set to something different, then pass in a different String.

For example, my [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TableFoo extends JPanel {
   private static final Vector<String> COLUMN_NAME_VECTOR = new Vector<String>(
         Arrays.asList(new String[] { "A", "B", "C" }));
   private static final int COLUMN_COUNT = COLUMN_NAME_VECTOR.size();
   private JTable table = new JTable();

   public TableFoo() {
      table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
      fillTableData();
      MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
      table.addMouseListener(myMouse);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }

   class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
       @Override
       public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
            final int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            final int column = table.getSelectedColumn();
            table.setValueAt("", row, column);
       }

   }

   public void fillTableData() {
      Vector<Vector<String>> matrix = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
      int rowCount = 8;
      for (int i = 0; i < rowCount ; i++) {
         Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>();
         for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN_COUNT; j++) {
            String rowText = String.format("row %d col %d", i, j);
            row.add(rowText );
         }
         matrix.add(row);
      }
      DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(matrix,
            COLUMN_NAME_VECTOR);
      table.setModel(model);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TableFoo mainPanel = new TableFoo();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableFoo");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: As I've mentioned above passing in `""` to `setValueAt` does not change the value in the GUI(same old value appears in the cell),

Comment: @Pranavan: then you've got a bug in code not shown. Notice that I've posted a small but complete and compilable/runnable program that demonstrates that `setValueAt(...)` ***does*** work. It is your responsibility to show us why ***your*** specific attempt to use this does not work, and again a valid [mre] program post (as I have posted in my answer) is likely the only way for you to achieve this.

Comment: @Pranavan: in fact, your posted code doesn't even show where or how you're calling `setValueAt(...)` ?! Why is this?